# Prove that $2<\int^2_1ln(x^2+1)+x<3$

Tags: calculus, integration

To show that $2<\int^2_1ln(x^2+1)+x$ , I took the derivative of the integrand and got that it's positive always in $[1,2]$, so its strictly increasing and the minimum in $[1,2]$ is at $x=1$, so $ln(2)+1<ln(x^2+1)+x$, and $ln(2)<ln(e)=1$ so: $ln(2)+1<2< ln(x^2+1)+x$ in $(1,2]$. 
EDIT: I just realized that the lower bound doesn't work too. 
About the upper bound I tried to substitute $2$ but it becomes $ln(5)+2>3$, so it doesn't really help. 
I would appreciate any help. 
 Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for $x\in [1.2] $. We have $ x-1< \ln(x^2+1)< x$ 
So :$\displaystyle \int_1^2(x-1)dx=\frac{1}{2}<\displaystyle\int_1^2\ln(x^2+1)dx<\displaystyle\int_1^2 xdx=\frac{3}{2}$
$\Rightarrow \frac{1}{2}+\displaystyle\int_1^2 xdx =2< \displaystyle\int_1^2 \ln(x^2+1)+x dx < \frac{3}{2}+\displaystyle\int_1^2 xdx =3$

Comment: mohamed Thanks!! I wonder, how did you reach that $x-1\le ln(x^2+1)\le x$ in $[1,2]$? is it just a straight fact that's good to know or there's some way to find that out?

Comment: This can be easily proven by studying the changes of the two functions on the domain $[1.2]$where $f(x)=\ln(x^2+1)-(x-1)$ and $ g(x)=x-\ln(x^2+1)$

Comment: What I meant is like how did you reach it, like I just went for derivative and couldn't think of anything to do after trying to bound the function. What I'm trying to understand what led you to bound the function with $x-1$ and $x$ out of everything? (Just trying to see what was your thought process while solving this question)

Comment: Look this $2-\int_1^2xdx=\frac{1}{2}=\int_1^2(x-1)dx\leq \int_1^2\ln(x^2+1)dx\leq 3-\int_1^2 xdx=\frac{3}{2}=\int_1^2xdx$ This prompted me directly to prove the study of the two functions $f (x) $ and $g (x)$ , and I found that to be valid to employ this idea in proof

Comment: mohamed Thanks for the help I appreciate it! I don't think I could've reached that conclusion alone

Comment: mohamed Sorry for bugging you again, but I noticed again that the question asks for $<$ without $\le$, how can I deal with that? can I say that if $f(x)<g(x)$ then the integrals are also $<$?

Comment: Yes of cours $g(x)\leq f(x)\rightarrow \int_a^b. g(x)\leq\int_a^b f(x)$

Comment: Yes but that proves $2 \le \int^2_1f(x) \le 3$ and not $<$ as the question asks

Comment: It doesn't matter in this $\leq$ Currently only just writing remains correct like this $\leq$ or like this .$<$. or I can modify that

Comment: Are you sure about it? everywhere I read about definite integral properties it's with $\le$ or $ge$ and not $<$ or $>$

Comment: What is the difference between $\leq$and $<$? In this case, the proof is correct in using either of them. Note well. I modified that \\ 
 Note.  :$(i<j )\leftrightarrow ( i\leq j  $and $i\neq j) $

Answer (score 1):

I began to solve this before Bacha's solution appeared, so I did not delete.

Hope I'm correct.
$$\int\ln(x^2+1)dx=(*)\\let\:f=\ln(x^2+1),g=x\\then\:df=\frac{2x}{x^2+1}dx,dg=dx\\\text{using integrating by parts where }\int fdg=dg-\int gdf\text{ we get}\\(*)=x\ln(x^2+1)-\int\frac{2x^2}{x^2+1}dx=x\ln(x^2+1)-2\int \left(1-\frac{1}{x^2+1}\right)dx=\\=x\ln(x^2+1)-2x+2\arctan(x)+C$$
And now calculate
$$\int\limits_1^2(\ln(x^2+1)+x)dx=\\=2\ln(2^2+1)-2*2+2\arctan(2)-\ln(1^2+1)+2*1-2\arctan(1)+\frac{1}{2}2^2-\frac{1}{2}1^2=\\=\ln\frac{25}{2}-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{\pi}{2}+2\arctan(2)$$
If we use calculator then $\ln\frac{25}{2}-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{\pi}{2}+2\arctan(2)\approx2.6692$. But if you want a more "honest" solution then we can *try* to estimate this from left and from right but it would hard... Nevertheless let's see how estimating would look.

From left:
$$\ln\frac{25}{2}-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{\pi}{2}+2\arctan(2)>\ln(e^2)-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{\pi}{2}+2\arctan(\sqrt{3})=2-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{\pi}{2}+\frac{2\pi}{3}=\\=1.5+\frac{\pi}{6}> 2$$
Ok.

From right:
$$\ln\frac{25}{2}-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{\pi}{2}+2\arctan(2)<\\<\left(\ln(e^2)+(\frac{25}{2}-e^2)*\frac{1}{e^2}\right)^{[2]}-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{\pi}{2}+2*\left(\arctan(\sqrt 3)+(2-\sqrt 3)*\frac{1}{\sqrt 3^2+1}\right)^{[1]}<\\<\left(2+5.5*\frac{1}{7}\right)-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{\pi}{2}+\left(\frac{2\pi}{3}+(2-\sqrt 3)*\frac{1}{2}\right)<\\<2.8-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{\pi}{2}+\frac{2\pi}{3}+(2-\sqrt 3)*\frac{1}{2}=2.3+\frac{\pi}{6}+(2-\sqrt 3)*\frac{1}{2}<2.3+\frac{\pi}{6}+0.3*\frac{1}{2}=\\=2.45+\frac{\pi}{6}<3$$
[1] $\forall x\geq 0:\:\arctan(x) + (x+\delta x)*\arctan'(x)\geq\arctan(x+\delta x)$ because $\forall y>x\geq 0:\: \arctan'(x)>\arctan'(y)$.

[2] Same as [1].

Ok, but too much work.